# FFTW vs fourn subroutine result does not match

Tags: fortran, fft, numerical-methods, fortran90, fftw

I'm converting/rewriting a old Fortran codebase to modern one. One of the segment of the code base uses fourn subroutine (from the Numerical receipies book) for FFT purpose. But when I'm trying to do that exact thing with the FFTW library it does not produce same result. I'm confused here. You can find the code the input data here : https://github.com/Koushikphy/fft_test/tree/master/notworking

The code that uses `fourn`:

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n=65536
    complex(kind=8) ::inp(n) = 0.0d0
    real(kind=8) :: sn, urt(2*n)
    integer :: i, ii

    sn = 1.0d0/sqrt(real(n,kind=8))

    do i=1,9070
        read(75,'(i4, 2f20.16)') ii, inp(i)
    enddo


    do i=1,n
        urt(2*i-1)= real(inp(i))
        urt(2*i) = aimag(inp(i))
    enddo

    ! forward
    call fourn(urt,[n],1,1)

    do i=1,n
        write(201,'(i4, 2f20.16)')i, urt(2*i-1), urt(2*i)
    enddo

end program test




SUBROUTINE FOURN(DATA,NN,NDIM,ISIGN)
    INTEGER ISIGN,NDIM,NN(NDIM)
! C      REAL DATA(*)
    DOUBLE PRECISION DATA(*)
    INTEGER I1,I2,I2REV,I3,I3REV,IBIT,IDIM,IFP1,IFP2,IP1,IP2,IP3,K1,K2,N,NPREV,NREM,NTOT
! C      REAL TEMPI,TEMPR
    DOUBLE PRECISION TEMPI,TEMPR
    DOUBLE PRECISION THETA,WI,WPI,WPR,WR,WTEMP
    NTOT=1
    DO IDIM=1,NDIM
       NTOT=NTOT*NN(IDIM)
    ENDDO
    NPREV=1
    DO IDIM=1,NDIM
       N=NN(IDIM)
       NREM=NTOT/(N*NPREV)
       IP1=2*NPREV
       IP2=IP1*N
       IP3=IP2*NREM
       I2REV=1
       DO I2=1,IP2,IP1
          IF (I2.LT.I2REV) THEN
             DO I1=I2,I2+IP1-2,2
                DO I3=I1,IP3,IP2
                   I3REV=I2REV+I3-I2
                   TEMPR=DATA(I3)
                   TEMPI=DATA(I3+1)
                   DATA(I3)=DATA(I3REV)
                   DATA(I3+1)=DATA(I3REV+1)
                   DATA(I3REV)=TEMPR
                   DATA(I3REV+1)=TEMPI
                ENDDO
             ENDDO
          ENDIF
          IBIT=IP2/2
 1        IF ((IBIT.GE.IP1).AND.(I2REV.GT.IBIT)) THEN
             I2REV=I2REV-IBIT
             IBIT=IBIT/2
             GOTO 1
          ENDIF
          I2REV=I2REV+IBIT
       ENDDO
       IFP1=IP1
 2     IF (IFP1.LT.IP2) THEN
          IFP2=2*IFP1
          THETA=ISIGN*6.28318530717959D0/(IFP2/IP1)
          WPR=-2.0D0*SIN(0.5D0*THETA)**2
          WPI=SIN(THETA)
          WR=1.0D0
          WI=0.0D0
          DO I3=1,IFP1,IP1
             DO I1=I3,I3+IP1-2,2
                DO I2=I1,IP3,IFP2
                   K1=I2
                   K2=K1+IFP1
                   TEMPR=SNGL(WR)*DATA(K2)-SNGL(WI)*DATA(K2+1)
                   TEMPI=SNGL(WR)*DATA(K2+1)+SNGL(WI)*DATA(K2)
                   DATA(K2)=DATA(K1)-TEMPR
                   DATA(K2+1)=DATA(K1+1)-TEMPI
                   DATA(K1)=DATA(K1)+TEMPR
                   DATA(K1+1)=DATA(K1+1)+TEMPI
                ENDDO
             ENDDO
             WTEMP=WR
             WR=WR*WPR-WI*WPI+WR
             WI=WI*WPR+WTEMP*WPI+WI
          ENDDO
          IFP1=IFP2
          GOTO 2
       ENDIF
       NPREV=N*NPREV
    ENDDO
    RETURN
    END
```

The code that uses `fftw`:

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n=65536
    complex(kind=8) :: inp(n)=0.0d0
    integer(kind=8) :: plan
    real(kind=8) :: sn
    integer :: i, ii


    sn = 1.0d0/sqrt(real(n,kind=8))
    call dfftw_plan_dft_1d(plan,n,inp,inp,-1,0)  !forward plan


    do i=1,9070
        read(75,'(i4, 2f20.16)') ii, inp(i)
    enddo


    ! forward transform
    call dfftw_execute_dft(plan, inp, inp)

    do i =1,n
        write(101,'(i4, 2f20.16)') i, inp(i)
    enddo
end program test
```

And the input file `fort.75` can be found here https://github.com/Koushikphy/fft_test/blob/master/notworking/fort.75

For, test I have also done a test with a different input where I've done FFT for a `sin` data, where the result match perfectly (https://github.com/Koushikphy/fft_test/tree/master/working).
The fftw approach

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n=65536
    real, parameter :: pi = 4.0*atan(1.0)
    complex(kind=8), dimension(n) :: x,y,grid,sin2y,out
    integer(kind=8) :: pForward, pBackward
    real(kind=8) :: sn
    integer :: i

    sn = 1.0d0/sqrt(real(n,kind=8))
    call dfftw_plan_dft_1d(pForward,n,x,y,-1,0)  !forward plan
    call dfftw_plan_dft_1d(pBackward,n,x,y,+1,0)! backward plan


    grid = [(i*2*pi/n, i=1,n)]
    sin2y = sin(2*grid)


    !actual data
    write(100,'(2f20.16)')sin2y




    ! forward transform
    call dfftw_execute_dft(pForward, sin2y, out)
    out = out*sn
    write(101,'(2f20.16)') out

    ! backward transform
    call dfftw_execute_dft(pBackward, out, sin2y)
    sin2y = sin2y*sn 

    write(102,'(2f20.16)') sin2y
end program test
```

and the `fourn` approach

```
program test
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: n=8192
    real, parameter :: pi = 4.0*atan(1.0)
    complex(kind=8), dimension(n) ::grid,sin2y
    real(kind=8) :: sn, urt(2*n)
    integer :: i, nn(1)

    sn = 1.0d0/sqrt(real(n,kind=8))
    grid = [(i*2*pi/n, i=1,n)]
    sin2y = sin(2*grid)


    !actual data
    write(200,'(2f20.16)')sin2y

    do i=1,n
        urt(2*i-1)= real(sin2y(i))
        urt(2*i) = aimag(sin2y(i))
    enddo

    nn = n

    ! forward
    call fourn(urt,nn,1,1)
    urt = urt*sn

    do i=1,n
        write(201,'(2f20.16)')urt(2*i-1:2*i)
    enddo


    !backward
    call fourn(urt,nn,1,-1)
    urt = urt*sn

    do i=1,n
        write(202,'(2f20.16)')urt(2*i-1:2*i)
    enddo


end program test
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't know how to put a large data in the question itself. "Elite" people of stackoverflow may guide me on that instead of putting a `close` vote

Comment: I'm wondering if it is okay to use the same array for the input and output arrays of FFT in the lines "dfftw_plan_dft_1d(plan,n,inp,inp,-1,0)" and "dfftw_execute_dft(plan, inp, inp)"? (just guessing...)

Comment: @roygvib I've frequently used that way and never faced any problem. You can use different array and still get the same error.

Comment: Provided all the codes, inputs and everything to perfectly reproduce the error, still got closed. Can anyone tell me what are the changes I have to make to get it open

Comment: @Euler I've made one reopen vote (because the question seems to have much details), but not sure it will be opened (I guess 4 or 5 such votes are needed...)

Comment: @roygvib, three votes in total are required to reopen.  However, I for one voted "remain closed".  Without a [mre] in the question we're left to guess what is going wrong on the basis of "it does not produce same result".  With detail about how the results differ (sign, factors of the square root of pi, etc.) or some indication of the properties of the failing input data completeness of the question may not be as important.

Comment: @francescalus Thanks for the info, and I'm a bit surprised that the question was actually re-opened for this question... So I've played around with it, and the main problem seems the definition of DFT in Numerical Recipes (though there may be other problems also...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the problem is due to the different definition of discrete FFT in FFTW and Numerical Recipes. Specifically, according to the [manual page](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029.html#The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029), the "forward"  FFT in FFTW are defined as

[image]

(which corresponds to `FFTW_FORWARD = -1` as defined in `fftw3.f`). On the other hand, the "forward" FFT in Numerical Recipes (NR) seems to be defined with exp(+i ...), according to Sec.12.4: "FFT in Two or More Dimensions" and eq.(12.4.1) (in the "NR in Fortran" book). The [header part](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Ejdiehl/Potential_Fields/fourn.f) of `fourn()` says:

> Replaces data by its ndim-dimensional discrete Fourier transform,
> if `isign` is input as 1. (...snip...)
> If `isign` is input as −1, data is replaced by its
> inverse transform times the product of the lengths of all dimensions.

so it seems that the "forward" transform in FFTW corresponds to the "backward" transform in NR. Since both FFTW and `fourn()` do not normalize the results in any step, I think we can just change the `isign` from 1 to -1 to compare the results:

```
...
urt(:) = 0  !<--- clear the entire urt(:) by zero...

do i=1,n
    urt(2*i-1) = real(inp(i))
    urt(2*i)   = aimag(inp(i))
enddo

! forward
!call fourn(urt, [n], 1, 1)  !<--- uses exp(+i ...) for "forward" transform in NR
call fourn(urt, [n], 1, -1)  !<--- uses exp(-i ...) for "backward" transform in NR
...
```

Then, both the codes give the same result for the input file `fort.75` (with the Re-Im curves shown below, which match between NR and FFTW).

[image]

For the second code using the sin data, the results of the "forward" transform are different between FFTW and NR (i.e. complex-conjugate to each other), while they become identical if we flip `isign` in `fourn()` (as expected).

Comment: The FFTW version is the (slightly) more "natural" one if one takes an interpolation point-of-view. That is, one places the data points `X_k` on the unit circle and interpolates `X_k = c(z_k)` with some polynomial `c(z)` having positive and negative exponents, `z_k=exp(i*2*pi*k/N)`. Then extracting the coefficients `Y_k` of `c(z)` gives the formula with the minus signs in the exponent, as in the cited formula. +1